# Show that $f(z)$ has at least two zeros (complex analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, maximum-principle

Let $f$ be a non-constant analytic function in $D=1<|z|<2$ with $|f|\equiv5$ on the boundary (assume $f$ is continuous on $\overline D$). Show that $f$ has at least two zeros.

My opinion: Based on maximum module principle, we have $|f(z)|\leq 5$ for any $z \in D$. Suppose $f$ doesn't have zero in that region $D$, then we have $1/|f(z)|=1/5$ on the boundary and $1/|f(z)|<1/5$ (based on maximum module principle theorem and the fact that $f(z)$ is non-constant). However, it contracts to $|f(z)|\leq 5$, which implies that $|f(z)|\geq 1/5$ for any $z \in D$. That's why $f(z)$ has to have at least one zero in $D$. But how can I prove $f$ has at least two zeroes?

Comment: If $f$ is analytic on that set, then what sense does $f$ on the boundary make?

Comment: I think we can assume f should be continuous on the boundary, but I think it is not necessary to have this condition

Comment: Since the problem refers to $f$ on the boundary, it would be nice if you could edit the question to make clear what that means.

Comment: OK,I will fix it!

Comment: What about $f(z) = \frac{5}{2} z$? It's not constant and $|f| = 5$ on the boundary right? It doesn't have any zeros on D.

Comment: @PiotrBenedysiuk: $|f|=5$ on *both*  boundary componenents of the annulus is assumed.

Comment: You can use the argument principle. The circle  $|z|=2$  in counterclockwise orientation is mapped to the circle $|z|=5$, also in counterclockwise orientation. So the change in the argument of $f$ over $|z|=2$ is at least (+) $2\pi$. Consider in a similar way the circle $|z|=1$.

Comment: Did you get the solution?